# Weird characters sent to ssh terminal when Alt+Tab between apps

Tags: ssh, terminal, vim, gnome-terminal, escape-characters

I **ssh** to my AWS EC2 machine with **Amazon Linux** from local **Ubuntu** with **GNOME Terminal**. If open **vim** in the **ssh** session and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> from terminal to another app and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back, annoying messages appear: `E349: No identifier under cursor` or `Press ENTER or type command to continue`. After some digging I've figured out the reason: weird characters are sent to **ssh terminal** when I Alt+Tab:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-121 ~]$ cat
^[[O^[[I^[[O^[[I^[[O^[[I^[[O^[[I^[[O^[[I
```

`^[[O^[[I` per single <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. What do these characters mean? Why are they sent and how to prevent their occurrence?

EDIT: Fixed by restarting GNOME Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

That's the terminal sending xterm's [focus-in/focus-out](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-FocusIn_FocusOut) escapes.  vim's set the terminal into a mode that lets it know when the cursor leaves the window (which it does when alt-tabbing).

You would *prevent* that by changing the mode used in vim for handling the mouse.  Checking xterm's documentation, vim would have to send a particular escape sequence with `1004` parameter (to tell xterm to send those escapes), but I do not see that in vim's [source-code](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/7ebcba61b20d25d23109fff73d0346ad44ba1b3b/src/os_unix.c#L3666). Some other terminal may be doing this as a side-effect of the mouse-movement mode `1003` (which vim does send):

```
    if (xterm_mouse_vers > 0)
    {
        if (on) // enable mouse events, use mouse tracking if available
            out_str_nf((char_u *)
               (xterm_mouse_vers > 1
            ? (
#ifdef FEAT_BEVAL_TERM
                bevalterm_ison
                   ? IF_EB("\033[?1003h", ESC_STR "[?1003h") :
#endif
                  IF_EB("\033[?1002h", ESC_STR "[?1002h"))
            : IF_EB("\033[?1000h", ESC_STR "[?1000h")));
        else    // disable mouse events, could probably always send the same
            out_str_nf((char_u *)
                   (xterm_mouse_vers > 1
                ? IF_EB("\033[?1002l", ESC_STR "[?1002l")
                : IF_EB("\033[?1000l", ESC_STR "[?1000l")));
        mouse_ison = on;
    }
```

You probably should consult the user manual of the terminal you are using, to see what the expected behavior would be with vim.